# can paprika or other dried spice be substituted for red bell peppers?

Tags: substitutions

Can paprika or other dry spice can be substituted for red bell peppers?  This recipe call for 1/2 medium red bell pepper, but a child will not eat the red peppers and I am hoping that using a dried spice will enable me to serve the dish.

Comment: What's the dish?  You can often just leave an ingredients out if it's not the main item in the dish.  You might also be able to chop up a vegetable finely enough that they're not noticed for things that get cooked down.  (eg, tomato sauce)

Comment: Will the child eat an orange or yellow pepper? [or even a white or purple, much harder to find] Kids are sometimes just like that - they decide they don't like something based on its colour rather than flavour ;) Orange or yellow would be an almost direct replacement, whereas a green would have a noticeably different flavour, though might still work depending on the recipe.

Comment: Although paprika is made from dried peppers, it has a very different flavour from a fresh pepper! You'll be lacking in sweetness. It may be worth adding the recipe in above so that a suitable alternative can be suggested. I tend to use tomatoes as a substitute when cooking for my mum (who is allergic to pepper) but won't work for all meals